# Check if a given point is within the boundary of the rotated element

Tags: javascript, html, math, geometry

I have a rectangle that  rotated 45°  degree as shown below, I have the points of all four corners, I need to find out if given point is within the boundary of the rotated rectangle. Note that rotation will change to any number, so somehow rotation need to be part of the formula.

**So we have:**

Width: 10

Height: 10

Rotation degree: 45°

Coordinates of rotated rectangle: A B C D

Given coordinates: E

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) might be useful depending on how you create the element.

Comment: i am afraid the `getBoundingClientRect()` is not a solution, imagine that the point `E` is out side the box between `A` and `B`; using `getBoundingClientRect` will falsely indicate that the point `E` is within the box, because it will return overall dimension.

Comment: What are width and height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't have the transform matrix for the rectangle.

If you do have the matrix then multiply the point by the inverse transform matrix. Then just test the point against the bounds of the rectangle top,left, right, and bottom

### Point inside convex polygon

Consider a convex polygon with points going around in a clockwise direction.

A point is inside that polygon if it is to the left of every edge (line) of the polygon.

If the point is right of one or more edges it is outside the polygon.

Left is defined as your left as if standing at the start of the line looking along its length. Or looking at a clock face with minute hand at 3 then left of minute hand is at 4 and right is at 2.

### Cross product

To find out which side a point is of a line you get the cross product of the vector from the line start to end, and the vector from the line start to the point. If the cross product is positive the point is to the left, if zero it is on the line, else it is to the right.

### Is left

```
const Point = (x, y) => ({x, y});
const Line = (p1, p2) => ({p1, p2});

function isPointLeft(l, p) { // l is line, p is point
    return 0 < (l.p2.x - l.p1.x) * (p.y - l.p1.y) - (l.p2.y - l.p1.y) * (p.x - l.p1.x);
}
```

### Clockwise check

Thus give a set of points in clockwise order that represent a rectangle check each side against the point. If all left you are inside.

Function returns true if point is inside polygon. Assumes points for polygon are in clockwise order

```
function isPointInsidePoly(point, poly) {
    var i = 0;
    const line = Line(poly[poly.length - 1]);
    while (i < poly.length) {
         line.p2 = poly[i++];
         if (!isPointLeft(line, point)) { return false }
         line.p1 = line.p2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

### Demo

Simple demo creates a set of points and rotates a rectangle.

Renders each point. If point is inside rectangle then point is drawn a little larger.

```js
const Point = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x, y});
const Line = (p1, p2) => ({p1, p2});
function isPointLeft(l, p) { // l is line, p is point
    return 0 < (l.p2.x - l.p1.x) * (p.y - l.p1.y) - (l.p2.y - l.p1.y) * (p.x - l.p1.x);
}
function isPointInsidePoly(point, poly) {
    var i = 0;
    const line = Line(poly[poly.length - 1]);
    while (i < poly.length) {
         line.p2 = poly[i++];
         if (!isPointLeft(line, point)) { return false }
         line.p1 = line.p2;
    }
    return true;
}


requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const [W, H] = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
const setOf = (count, cb, i = 0, a = []) => {while (i < count) { a.push(cb(i++)) } return a}
function drawPoint(p, size) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
}
const rect = {
    x: W / 2, y: H / 2,// x,y center of rectangle
    w: 80, h: 20,      // w h from center
    points: [Point(), Point(), Point(), Point()],
    update(angle) {
        const transform = (x, y, res) => {
            res.x = x * ax - y * ay + this.x;
            res.y = x * ay + y * ax + this.y;
        }
        const [ax, ay] = [Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle)];
        const p = this.points;
        transform( this.w,  this.h, p[0]);
        transform(-this.w,  this.h, p[1]);
        transform(-this.w, -this.h, p[2]);
        transform( this.w, -this.h, p[3]);  
    },
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const p of this.points) { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y) }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
     }
}; 
const testPoints = setOf(20, () => Point(rand(20, W - 20), rand(20, H - 20)));
function renderLoop(time) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    rect.update(time / 2300);
    rect.draw(ctx);
    for (const p of testPoints) {
        if (isPointInsidePoly(p, rect.points)) { drawPoint(p, 3) }
        drawPoint(p, 1);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any polytope can be represented as a finite intersection of closed half-spaces. Halfspaces are given by linear inequalities such as x+y+5<=0 which is the lower part of the line going through (-5,0) and (0,-5).

See any book on convexity or the Wikipedia link for details:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope#Properties
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)

Comment: thanks for the heads up, look like i need to learn some serious math.

Answer (score 1):

You will need first to get the center of the rectangle by calculating the average coordinates of any two opposite corners. Then, you will need also to get the two dimensions of the rectangle which can be achieved by determinering the point with the largest y value along with the two points of the smallest and largest x values. The horizontal dimension, before rotation, is the distance between the first and second points, and the vertical dimension, before rotation, is the distance between the first and third points.

The next step is to check if point E is close enough to the center of the rectangle to be inside it or not. The simplest way is to check its horizontal and vertical distances, before rotation, from the center, if they are less than, or equal to if you are good with being on edges, half the respective dimension, then it is inside the rectangle. You can get the original horizontal and vertical distances before rotation using the appropriate [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for any rotation angle.

```
// center of rectangle
xO = (xA + xC) / 2;
yO = (yA + yC) / 2;
// point of largest y value
xPymax = xA;
yPymax = yA;
if (yB > yPymax)
{
    xPymax = xB;
    yPymax = yB;
}
if (yC > yPymax)
{
    xPymax = xC;
    yPymax = yC;
}
if (yD > yPymax)
{
    xPymax = xD;
    yPymax = yD;
}
// point of smallest x value
xPxmin = xA;
yPxmin = yA;
if (xB < xPxmin)
{
    xPxmin = xB;
    yPxmin = yB;
}
if (xC < xPxmin)
{
    xPxmin = xC;
    yPxmin = yC;
}
if (xD < xPxmin)
{
    xPxmin = xD;
    yPxmin = yD;
}
// point of largest x value
xPxmax = xA;
yPxmax = yA;
if (xB > xPxmax)
{
    xPxmax = xB;
    yPxmax = yB;
}
if (xC > xPxmax)
{
    xPxmax = xC;
    yPxmax = yC;
}
if (xD > xPxmax)
{
    xPxmax = xD;
    yPxmax = yD;
}
// dimensions of the rectangle
H = Math.sqrt((xPymax - xPxmin) * (xPymax - xPxmin) + (yPymax - yPxmin) * (yPymax - yPxmin));
V = Math.sqrt((xPymax - xPxmax) * (xPymax - xPxmax) + (yPymax - yPxmax) * (yPymax - yPxmax));
// calculating the original distances of point E from center
xdE = (xE - xO) * Math.cos(rot) + (yE - yO) * Math.sin(rot);
ydE = -(xE - xO) * Math.sin(rot) + (yE - yO) * Math.cos(rot);
// comparing to the dimentions of the rectangle
if (Math.abs(xdE) <= H / 2 && Math.abs(ydE) <= V / 2)  // this will consider a point on any edge as inside the rectangle, if you don't want this, just remove "="
    // the point is inside the rectangle
else
    // the point is outside the rectangle
```